# expand array to string in powershell

Tags: powershell

Well my English is too bad to explain what i want but i will try

There are some very big multiline string - part of sql query

```
$q =
     "Values 
        (
            '$($line.'common.uuid')',
            '$($line.'user.user_id')',
            '$($line.'user.ldap.user_attributes.displayName')',
            '$($line.'user.email_address')',
            '$($line.'common.owner')',
            '$($line.'common.current_phone_number')',
            '$($line.'common.current_country_name')',
        )"
```

That string is very hard to edit
Are there any way to do like that in simple way? Or only something like foreach $field in $fields?

```
$fields = '
common.uuid
user.user_id
user.ldap.user_attributes.displayName
user.email_address
.....'

$q = '(
$line.($fields somehow here)
)'
```

There can be about 100 lines of values and its much easier to edit that list in $fields instead of $q

Thanks!

Comment: How are you querying your SQL db? It sounds like you'll want to parameterize the query before doing anything else...

Comment: Yes, its export from some system to mssql

Comment: Right, but can you show us the rest of the code? The code that actually executes the query

Answer (score 3):

As [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out, it is generally preferable to use a *parameterized* SQL query than to use *string interpolation* to bake values into a query string, not least for better security, but also to avoid round-trip conversion to and from strings for non-string values.

If you do want to stick with your string-interpolation approach, here's a solution based on the `.psobject` [intrinsic member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members), which is a rich source of reflection about any object and allows enumerating its properties via the `.Properties` collection:

```sh
# Sample input object.
$line = [pscustomobject] @{ 
  'common.uuid' = '1-2-3'; 
  'user.user_id' = 'jdoe'; 
}

# Use string interpolation to embed all of the object's property values.
$q = @"
Values (
  $($line.psobject.Properties.Value.ForEach({ "'" + $_ + "'" }) -join ",`n  ")
)
"@
```

This solution makes **two assumptions**:

- You're interested in the values of *all* properties of the input object.
- You do *not* need *nested* property access (in the code in your question, a property access such as `.'user.user_id'` is a *single* property access targeting a property named *verbatim* `user.user_id`, even though the name itself suggests a property *path* (nested access)).

If these assumptions don't hold, see [Daniel's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69236435/45375).

Note that, as in your question, all values are represented as *strings* (`'...'`) in the resulting query fragment.

If you choose a parameterized-query approach instead, you can similarly use `$line.psobject.Properties.Value` to obtain an array of all property values. (Note that even though `.Value` is applied to a *collection* of elements, PowerShell conveniently collects its *elements'* `.Value` values, which is a feature known as [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375)).

The above stores the following in variable `$q`:

```
Values (
  '1-2-3',
  'jdoe'
)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's string interpolation via *expandable strings* (`"..."`).

Answer (score 1):

As usual, [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) offers a [great approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69236260/11954025) looping through the object's properties directly, though you may have to rearrange the sql statement to accommodate the order of the properties and/or add some additional filtering if you are not interested in all of the properties on the object.

I will go ahead and post my solution as it may offer some additional insight to how this can be done.

```
# Example object data
$lines = @(
    @{
        common = @{
            uuid                 = 'some uuid'
            owner                = 'some owner'
            current_phone_number = '222-555-1212'
            current_country_name = 'USA'
        }
        user   = @{
            user_id       = 'some userid'
            email_address = 'some@email.add'
            ldap          = @{user_attributes = @{displayName = 'Some User' } }
        }
    }
    @{
        common = @{
            uuid                 = 'some other uuid'
            owner                = 'some other owner'
            current_phone_number = '222-555-1212'
            current_country_name = 'UK'
        }
        user   = @{
            user_id       = 'some other userid'
            email_address = 'some_other@email.add'
            ldap          = @{user_attributes = @{displayName = 'Some other User' } }
        }
    }
)

# Create an array of the fields we are interested in, 
# in the order we would like them to appear in the sql statement
$fields = @(
    'common.uuid',
    'user.user_id',
    'user.ldap.user_attributes.displayName',
    'user.email_address',
    'common.owner',
    'common.current_phone_number',
    'common.current_country_name'
)

# loop through the fields forming the line 
# and then join them together using -join
$values = ($fields | ForEach-Object {
        "`t'`$(`$line.$_)'"
    }) -join ',`n'

# add in the rest of the statement
$q = "Values (`n $values `n)"

foreach ($line in $lines) {
    # Use ExpandString to expand the variables inside
    # our $q string
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($q)
}
```

Output

```
Values (
        'some uuid',
        'some userid',
        'Some User',
        'some@email.add',
        'some owner',
        '222-555-1212',
        'USA'
)
Values (
        'some other uuid',
        'some other userid',
        'Some other User',
        'some_other@email.add',
        'some other owner',
        '222-555-1212',
        'UK'
)
```

Comment: Nice; I had assumed that the code in the question is functional, but  `common.uuid` may indeed be a _nested_ property access rather than a single property with an unusual name.

Comment: @mklement0 You are probably right.  That's how it looks judging from the single quotes surrounding the field names.  I thought it might be a typo though and went with my assumption.